# Show image in output with XML

Tags: php, xml

I have done the following code to extract an image from a URL, but I am getting an XML parsing error. How do I show an image with all XML output?

```
$error = true;
$msg = 'profile';
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
if($error)
{
    echo "<response>";
    echo "<success>S</success>";
    echo "<message>".trim($msg)."</message>";
    echo "<userid>".trim($userid)."</userid>";
    echo "<username>".trim($username)."</username>";
    echo "<firstname>".trim($firstname)."</firstname>";
    echo "<lastname>".trim($lastname)."</lastname>";
    echo "<email>".trim($email)."</email>";
    echo "<follower>".trim($follower)."</follower>";
    //echo "<photo><img src=photo/".trim($photo) ." height='200' width='200'></photo>";
    echo "</response>";
}
```

Comment: avoid forming XMLs like this. Use APIs/LIBs instead.

Comment: i don't think you can add an image to xml output, still you can just provide the URL to it, and render in some other way.

Comment: attributes in XMLs must be enclosed in `""` or `''`.

Comment: `trim` is not a good choice to encode text for XML output. Take a look at `htmlspecialchars` as well. And please consult an XML how-to of your choice how to write XML. An error message normally tells you what you did wrong.

Comment: So,what i can generate is "the path" for the image only?

Comment: @DoSparKot : APIs ? I mean how?

Comment: Can you provide a correct path with your question? Mabye an Internet link that is providing the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XML cannot use an <img src=...> tag to display images. That is a HTML tag. You can have an URL to the image which your application can read and then render, but that is application-specific (i.e. browser, mobile phone, or desktop application) - which is the point of XML, it's generic and not tied down to a single application.

Answer (score 3):

For such a simple XML chunk, you can make use of [PHP's SimpleXML API](http://php.net/book.simplexml) to generate the `<response>` XML chunk. For the XML document itself and the straight forward elements with no attributes it goes like:

```
$response          = new SimpleXMLElement('<response/>');
$response->success = 5;
$response->message = trim($msg);
```

For the photo element with the img child and the attributes, it goes like:

```
$img           = $response->addChild('photo')->addChild('img');
$img["src"]    = "photo/" . trim($photo);
$img["height"] = 200;
$img["width"]  = 200;
```

You find PHP examples similar to this and much more info in the PHP manual when you google for *"SimpleXML basic examples"*.

As you can see, you don't need to care about the XML encoding here, the SimpleXML API does this for you.

The output is then similar straight forward:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $response->asXML();
```

I hope this is helpful, exemplary output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response><success>5</success><message>profile</message><photo><img src="photo/nice-day.jpg" height="200" width="200"/></photo></response>
```

and beautified:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
    <success>5</success>
    <message>profile</message>
    <photo>
        <img src="photo/nice-day.jpg" height="200" width="200"/>
    </photo>
</response>
```

Comment: thanks for explaining it, but still I am not able to show image.

Comment: Well, fix the path to the image, that is likely your problem. You need to find out what the correct path is first and then use the correct path. There is not much I can do about that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single quote to `src` value and close the `img` tag

```
       $error=true;
       $msg='profile';
       header('Content-type: text/xml');
       echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
       if($error)
       {
               echo "<response>";
               echo "<success>S</success>";
               echo "<message>".trim($msg)."</message>";
               echo "<userid>".trim($userid)."</userid>";
               echo "<username>".trim($username)."</username>";
               echo "<firstname>".trim($firstname)."</firstname>";
               echo "<lastname>".trim($lastname)."</lastname>";
               echo "<email>".trim($email)."</email>";
               echo "<follower>".trim($follower)."</follower>";
               echo "<photo><img src='photo/".trim($photo)."' height='200' width='200'></img></photo>";
               echo "</response>";
       }
```